# Is there a CSS property I can set to make a character invisible?

Tags: html, css

My control buttons can have text in a number of different colors. However the current buttons need to have text that does not show. For this I add a class called `current` I realize I could change the colors but is there any property or way to retain color and make a character not visible?

Comment: use `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: [Agreed - @Nanne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676230/is-there-a-css-property-i-can-set-to-make-a-character-invisible/21676253#21676253)

Comment: `color:transparent` will also work - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yGnnv/)

Comment: What is the point in having text that isn't visible?

Comment: Why would you want to hide the text on these buttons? Sounds a bit unconventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `color: transparent;` or `visibility:hidden;`

Comment: [Agreed - @dream_machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21676230/is-there-a-css-property-i-can-set-to-make-a-character-invisible/21676253#21676253)

Answer (score 1):

Use `visibility:hidden;` to get what you are looking for.
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QWjnm/2/)